# Unable to autowire a field in UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I know there are some questions about this topic but mine is a little different. I'm trying to include openID authentication into my project developed with Spring, Spring-security and Spring-MVC.

To achieve the openID auth, some clases are necessary: AccessDeniedHandler and UserDetailsService are configured in applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- turn on global security -->
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

    <bean id="openIdAuthFailureHandler" class="es.institution.dept.security.MyAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="es.institution.dept.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl"/>

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/*" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/" />
        <security:openid-login login-page="/openidLogin" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="openIdAuthFailureHandler"/>
    </security:http>        

    <security:authentication-manager>
       <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
           users-by-username-query="
              SELECT username, password, active as enabled  
              FROM users WHERE username=?"  

           authorities-by-username-query="
              select ur.username, ur.rolename as authority from users_roles ur 
              where ur.username=?" />
       </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

UserDetailsService is called by Spring when it needs to know user data (username, password, roles...) For this reason, I need to call one of my services (UserService) in UserDetailsService:

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        es.institution.dept.model.User user = userService.getUserByUsername("mannuk");
        if(user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User does not exist");
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isActive(), false, false, false, getGrantedAuthorities(username));
    }

    public List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(String username) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (Role role : userService.getAllRoles(username)) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

I tried two options:

1)Define @Service annotation in UserDetailsService which throws an Exception during the start up. It says that UserDetails bean does not exist (it is necessary in applicationSecurity-context.xml)

2)Declare a bean definition in applicationContext-security.xml. The startup is OK (no errors) but the UserService is not autowired.

This is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/adminDB"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml" /> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="usersMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="es.institution.dept.dao.UserMapper" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="rolesMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="es.institution.dept.dao.RoleMapper" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="groupMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="es.institution.dept.dao.GroupMapper" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="policyMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="es.institution.dept.dao.PolicyMapper" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- Json converter bean --> 
    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"></bean>
</beans>
```

This is my app-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Enabling Spring beans auto-discovery -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="es.institution.dept" />

    <!-- Enabling Spring MVC configuration through annotations -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Enabling Spring Async tasks through annotations -->
    <task:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="login" />

    <!-- Load resources -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <!-- Bean definitions i18n -->

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <!--  Intercepts the change of the locale: example.html?ln=en -->
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="ln" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
        <property name="interceptors">
           <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Register the messages.properties -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/classes/locale/messages" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Defining which view resolver to use -->
    <bean class= "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" > 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" /> 
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Note that UserService is working fine in other places like controllers. It seems to be a problem with the UserDetailsService itself.

If you need more info do not hesitate to write to me. I hope to solve this issue. The solution will be voted and checked.

Answer (score 0):

- Beans declared in root application context (`applicationContext.xml` and `applicationContext-security.xml`) cannot access beans declared in servler-specific context (`app-servlet.xml`)
- Components of Spring Security (including `UserDetailsService`) must be declared in root application context

So, you need to declare `UserService` in `applicationContext.xml` instead of picking it up by `<context:component-scan>` in `app-servlet.xml`.

Comment: Is it possible to implement this in another way? I mean... In another app I have a bean declared in appContext (AutorizationManager) which autowires a service. Maybe, in the servlet I only have to scan es.institution.dept.controller. If I declare the bean UserService in appContext its fields are not autowired. Could you clarify me that?

Comment: If `UserService` depends on other beans from `app-servlet.xml`, you can move all content of `app-servlet.xml` to `applicationContext.xml`.  As far as I remember it should work without other changes.

Comment: UserService does not depend on beans in app-servlet.xml. UserService depends on DAO beans which I've declared in appContext.xml. Controller beans like UserController, AdminController depends on UserService. If I change es.institution.dept to es.institution.dept.controller, there are exceptions in the startup from the Controller beans:  Could not autowire field: es.institution.dept.service.UserService es.institution.dept.controller.AdminController.userService;. Do I need to include another component-scan in appContext?

Comment: If so, you can remove `@Service` from `UserService` (to exclude it from component-scan) and declare it in appContext manully.